# Can't find the button to click with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to click on the button on "https://euw.op.gg/summoner/userName=JengaSneaky". But I can't find the element that trigger it.

The pic shows one of the buttons. I want Selenium to click on it so I can scrape the data that pops up. I've tried to find the element but it says I can't use it with click().

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on how to better frame your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with these kind of buttons is that they are generated each time you load the html ( or the page ) based on the data contained in a database that changes everyday.
That's why they don't come with a unique id or something to distinguish them from others.

The thing you could do here is to find them by the CSS SELECTOR or by XPATH.
But you will always have to check if they changed everyday.

What you could also try to do is locate them if they contain a specific text.